# Why do I get error when trying to change directory to the mounted drive in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When using the command

```
        %cd '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/'
```

I get the error:

```
        ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
        Below is the traceback from this internal error.

        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in 
        run_code
            exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
          File "<ipython-input-48-1d7f4f899579>", line 1, in <module>
            get_ipython().magic("cd '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/'")
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2160, in 
        magic
            return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2081, in 
        run_line_magic
            result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
          File "<decorator-gen-91>", line 2, in cd
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 188, in <lambda>
             call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/osm.py", line 288, in cd
            oldcwd = py3compat.getcwd()
        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1823, in 
        showtraceback
            stb = value._render_traceback_()
          AttributeError: 'FileNotFoundError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1132, in 
        get_records
            return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 358, in 
        _fixed_getinnerframes
            records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
            frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
            filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
           File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
              if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
             File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 725, in getmodule
          file = getabsfile(object, _filename)
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 709, in getabsfile
                return os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(_filename))
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 383, in abspath
               cwd = os.getcwd()
          FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It was working fine before but when I  removed one folder and added one, it started to show this error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in between `My Drive`.

Try using:

```
%cd '/content/gdrive/My Drive/'
```

or

```
%cd '/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/'
```